# Image not showing with full width in splash screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using following code to display image as splash screen :

```
class WelcomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/welcome_page';

  @override
  _WelcomeWidgetState createState() => _WelcomeWidgetState();
}

class _WelcomeWidgetState extends State<WelcomeWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    
    super.initState();
    Timer(
      Duration(seconds: 10),
      () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => LowerStripWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      
      body: 
      Container(
        child:Center(
        child: Image.asset('assets/images/Splash-Screen-bg.png'),       
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
     
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This shows the image but does not stretch image to fill the white space.
How we can do that in flutter?

Here is the current screen:

[image]

Comment: Use the `fit` property of the `Image.asset` widget and set it to `BoxFit.cover`.

Comment: Thanks @TimilehinJegede. How we can also set the `fit` along with image path?

Comment: `Image.asset('assets/images/Splash-Screen-bg.png',fit: BoxFit.cover,),`

Comment: Happy Fluttering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `fit` property of the `Image` widget to determine how to inscribe the image into the space allocated during layout.

I added an example using your code:

```
Image.asset(
    'assets/images/Splash-Screen-bg.png',
     // set the fit property to cover
     it: BoxFit.cover, // new line
 ),
```